# direction tangent bundle of $S^2$ homeomorphism

Tags: quaternions, tangent-bundle, hopf-fibration

Let $\triangle S^{2}$ ( the tangent direction bundle of $S^2$) be the unit tangent bungle of $S^2$ where the opposite tangent directions are identified.
Let G be the (order four) group of quaternions generated by $i$. Let us identify the unit quaternions with $S^3$.
Find an homeomorphism between $\triangle S^{2}$  ans $S^3/G$ .
My best bet was trying to use the Hopf fibration to get a map from $S^3$ to $S^2$, and try to use the tangent direction to get a point in the inverse image of the hopf fibration up to $i$ , but even if both the tangent direction and the fiber of the hopf fibration are homeomorphoc to $S^1$, I was unable to find a way to link them continuously.

Comment: One natural way would be to view each of these spaces as the quotient of certain spaces by a $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ action and show that the non-quotiented spaces are isomorphic by a map which intertwines the two actions.